# Testing multi Auth in Laravel

Tags: laravel, testing

In my app, I use the Multi Authentication. (I used [this link](https://devmarketer.io/learn/setting-multi-authentication-laravel-5-4-part-1/))

It works, and I can log as a user -> I am redirected to "/home"

as an admin, when I log in, I am redirected to "/admin_home"

when connected, admin can't access to "/home", he is redirected to another page

But when I write this test :

```
class AdminTest extends TestCase
{
    public function setUp()
    {
        parent::setUp();
        Artisan::call('migrate');
        Artisan::call('db:seed');
    }

    public function tearDown()
    {
        Artisan::call('migrate:reset');
        parent::tearDown();
    }


    public function testCannotAccessUserSpace()
    {
        $admin = Admin::find(1);

        $response = $this->actingAs($admin, 'admin')
            ->get('/home');

        $response->assertStatus(200);
    }

}
```

I have a success response but I know the admin cannot access "home" space

What's wrong in my test ?

Comment: I suppose it has something to do with your redirecting, to test it out do `$response->assertRedirect($pageUrlWhereItRedirects);`

Comment: no, because if i write `$response->assertRedirect('/login');` it fails because the response is not a 302 but a 200. it should be a 302 to '/login' because it is what happens when i do it. I think `$this->actingAs($admin, 'admin')` doesn't play the test like an admin but why

Comment: I have a few questions. Is it possible to see the index action on your HomeController? Do you have a seperate login page for admins? I don't see anything wrong with the test itself and so I'm wondering if this has more to do with your implementation.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Okay, so after some struggle I've finally found the issue.

I implemented the multi-auth using the same [link](https://devmarketer.io/learn/setting-multi-authentication-laravel-5-4-part-1/).

The problem is in your `HomeController.php` not in the `AdminTest`.

Just like you have specified the authentication guard in your `AdminController.php` constructor, you have to do it in `HomeController.php` also.

As you know (assuming you've followed the link) for **AdminController.php** it is like this:

```
class AdminController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:admin');
    }
```

In here we've specified in the constructor that we need to authenticate against the `admin` guard but in HomeController we didn't.

**HomeController.php Before:**

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth');
    }
```

**HomeController.php After:**

```
class HomeController extends Controller
{
    /**
     * Create a new controller instance.
     *
     * @return void
     */
    public function __construct()
    {
        $this->middleware('auth:web');
    }
```

**Solution is**

> $this->middleware('auth');

changes to

> $this->middleware('auth:web');

Now, if you run the test it will show the following error:

```
PHPUnit 5.7.27 by Sebastian Bergmann and contributors.

F..                                                                 3 / 3 (100%)

Time: 124 ms, Memory: 10.00MB

There was 1 failure:

1) Tests\Feature\AdminTest::testCannotAccessUserSpace
Expected status code 200 but received 302.
Failed asserting that false is true.
```

Comment: thanks a lot, it works! i thougth because it was the default guard, i didn't have to specify it. but i was wrong.